# How to solve this system of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My doubt in this question would be by which method I have to solve it. I've seen some simple examples where these problems were solved by laplace properties. So I tried to solve by the properties of laplace, but I couldn't. Is there some other method to solve it or is this exercise worded incorrectly?
$$x'+4x+3y=0$$$$ y'+3x+4y=2e^t$$ $$x(0)=0, y(0)=0$$

Comment: In my book on ODE, I've solved systems of this type using two methods: Method (1): Write it as a first order system of linear ODEs, find the fundamental matrix $e^{A t}$, and find the unique solution of the IVP using the general formula for the non-homogeneous case. Method (2): Use Laplace transforms to directly solve the system of ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, so...

There is another, relatively low-tech, method which you can try, and that is to eliminate one variable and its derivatives to form a second order linear DE.

So, for example, by eliminating $y$ and $y'$ you arrive at $$x''+8x'+7x=-6e^t$$

and this leads to the general solution for $x$, namely $$x=Ae^{-t}+Be^{-7t}-\frac12e^t$$

From there you can apply the initial conditions and obtain the solution for $y$ as well.